# blender not responding after install appleseed engine and blenderseed add on

Tags: add-on

[image]
I had installed **APPLESEED** Engine and add an add-on ***blenderseed*** in blender BUT IT SHOW messages that show in image *blender not responding* and second one pls Look in the image.

Comment: Please don't use all caps, it is considered rude

Comment: I think the issue will be related to appleseed or its addon, you would get better help with someone who knows appleseed. Try asking for help at the [appleseed forum](https://forum.appleseedhq.net/c/help)